# Decoding JSON and passing to view in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am new to Laravel, and am working on a small project that lists a set of snacks to be worked with. The snacks are managed in an API and returned as JSON. I am having  hard time trying to decode the JSON properly and then pass the results into my view, where I will loop over it to build a list the user will work with. Here is the SnackController.php:

```
public function index()
{

    $snacks = file_get_contents('https://api-snacks.snacklabs.com/v1/snacks/?ApiKey=randomKey');

    $snacks = json_decode($snacks, true);

    return view('all-snacks', ['snacks' => $snacks]);
}
```

I have tried with and without decoding the data with no luck. I also tried using a Laravel accessor, and ensuring the JSON is UTF-8 encoded. I continue to get an error in my view that`htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given`.

This is all I have in my .blade.php just to even test I can get the data passed properly:

```
<div>
    {{ $snacks }}
</div>
```

Note that {{ $snacks[0] }} or {{ $snacks->id }} all yield the same error regardless.

I have been searching for a solution for a while and I am stuck. I can pass the raw JSON to the view, but I can't actually work with it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think, you are wrong render $snacks in blade template.

Now, snacksis array, write `<?php print_r($snacks)?>` and you will see all json data and right array keys

Comment: This works yes, and I had a similar solution but it isn't the most ideal in this particular situation

Answer (score 0):

There might be some small mistake in your view code.

It mentions that, you are trying to assign array value to some form element, which doesn't support the array value.

Example: `{{ Form::text('category_id', $categories) }}`, where $categories is an array. So, it would throw the same error. Instead, it should be `Form::select('category_id', $categories);`

Also, take a look at this reference: http://laravel.io/forum/05-16-2014-htmlentities-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string-array-given-error-exception

Comment: I came across that particular post, but I don't think it applies because I don't have any forms or similar elements in my Blade. I edited my original post to show what is in the  Blade

Comment: Ok. You could try dd($snacks) and check the output. That way, you would have an idea about what $snacks contains.

Comment: yea I was doing that all along and didn't realize the answer was staring me in the face the whole time. I was able to solve my own problem though!

Answer (score 0):

Dammit its been a long day, I was just forgetting to be more specific about what I was trying to display. For example

```
{{ $snacks }}
```

is correct to spit out the error, when it should have been

```
{{ $snacks[0]['name'] }}
```